# Excel Interop in VB getting error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to add information to a sheet row by row.
I keeps giving me an error if I + 1 anything.

If I just directly change a cell, it works fine and no errors or crashes like so

```
ws.Cells(2, 1) = "Test Data"
```

But as soon as I try to auto step through my rows, it crashes.

Any ideas? I've googled alot, but it seems 0x800A03EC is a generic error code.

Here is my code

```
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workBook As Excel.Workbook

    workBook = app.Workbooks.Open("P:\CAD\RhinoDek\Color Storage\TWO_SHEETS.xlsx")
    ws = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim uRange = ws.UsedRange
    Dim rRange = uRange.Rows

    Dim cRow = rRange.Count + 1

    ws.Cells(cRow, 1) = "Test Data" (It throws the error here at cRow)

    workBook.Save()
    workBook.Close()
    app.Quit()
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: can you put a `Messagebox.Show(cRow)` before line which is the error, and see what is the value of `cRow`

Comment: cRow is 1048576. Not exactly sure with it's that's so darn high either.

Comment: the problem that you have reached the maximum number of rows in Excel!

Comment: how many rows in your file `TWO_SHEETS.xlsx`

Comment: That is the last row. 1048576. But they are all empty! What the hell did I do?

Comment: how many rows used that have data in your file TWO_SHEETS.xlsx

Comment: This is brand new xlsx file. I create a test file called TWO_SHEETS and started to test adding data to. All the rows are empty. I am not sure why excel created so many empty rows, unless that's be default. I just want to get the last used row, plus one, and add data. I can do it in VBA just fine, but doing this in VB.net is a pain for some reason.

Comment: Can you try code in the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have reached the maximum number of rows in Excel.

Try this to get last used row  :

```
dim cRow = ws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.XlUp).row +1
```

or

```
dim cRow = ws.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Row +1
```

Comment: Well.... after looking over what you supplied, I scrolled all the way down... and there it was.... a random number that I must have put there on accident. I deleted that an poof, it started working lol. Thanks man!!